# How to use trackedRaycast(_:updateHandler:) method in ARKit?

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

> Repeats a ray-cast query over time to notify you of updated surfaces in the physical environment.

How to use this func in ARKit?

```
func trackedRaycast(_ query: ARRaycastQuery, 
              updateHandler: @escaping ([ARRaycastResult]) -> Void) -> ARTrackedRaycast?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Apple Developer documentation says the following about `trackedRaycast()`**:

> `trackedRaycast(_:updateHandler:)` instance method repeats a ray-cast query over time to notify you of updated surfaces in the physical environment. A tracked ray cast wraps a ray-cast query that the `ARSession` calls repeatedly, each time invoking your update handler to provide you with new results. When you're ready to stop a tracked ray cast, call `stopTracking()`.

So, here's a code snippet that you can use in your project:

```
import RealityKit
import ARKit

@IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
let scene = try! Experience.loadScene()

let raycastQuery: ARRaycastQuery = .init(origin: [0,0,0],
                                      direction: [7,7,7],
                                       allowing: .estimatedPlane,
                                      alignment: .horizontal)

let repeatRaycast = self.arView.session.trackedRaycast(raycastQuery) { results in

    // Update Handler's content
    guard let result: ARRaycastResult = results.first
    else { return }

    let anchor = AnchorEntity(world: result.worldTransform)
    anchor.addChild(self.scene)

    self.arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
}
```

Then you can stop tracking:

```
repeatRaycast?.stopTracking()
```

Comment: I generally don't recommend using the `.init(origin: , direction: , allowing: , alignment: )` initializer unless 1) you understand the `origin` and `direction` vectors very well, and 2) you need to raycast from something besides the user's/phone's perspective. The `.init(from: , allowing: , alignment: )` initializer is usually all you need.

Comment: Thank you for a useful tip, @jfriesenhahn.

Answer (score 1):

First define a query with something like

```
let bounds = sceneView.bounds
let screenCenter = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
let query = sceneView.raycastQuery(from: screenCenter, allowing: .estimatedPlane, alignment: .horizontal)
```

Then initiate trackedRaycast with update handler:

```
let trackedRaycast = sceneView.castTrackedRay(for: query, updateHandler: { results in
    guard let result = results.first else { return }
    // Do something with results
    // Maybe adjust a relevent node's position
    someNode.simdWorldPosition = result.worldTransform.position
})
```

Then, if at some point you don't need to track it/update position anymore, you can stop the `updateHandler` execution: `trackedRaycast?.stopTracking()`

Note that if a normal raycast would fail either because of query constraints or scene trouble, then a trackedRaycast will also fail and your `trackedRaycast` object will be `nil`.